# session.rollback deletes data previously queried from the database.

Tags: python, transactions, sqlalchemy, rollback

## The Problem

Calling SQLAlchemy's `session.rollback()` after hitting a DB integrity error (requirement of SQLAlchemy) causes all session objects to be disposed. This includes objects created by previous selects.

Looking at the SQL generated our query data is caught in an implicit transaction that isn't finished until after we do `session.close`.

### Simplified SQL Example

```
Begin (implicit) transaction
SELECT Data
# Should be end transaction here
# Should Start new Transaction
INSERT New Data
# hit integrity error
rollback
```

## Problem Section

```
try:
    self.session.add(insertable['cluster'])
    self.session.commit()
except IntegrityError:
    print('Prevented from inserting duplicate to cluster table')
    self.session.rollback()
# insertable is now an empty object and can't be used without repopulating
```

What this means is that in the worst case we'll have an integrity error on every insert and we'll need to re-select the row IDs for each insert.

## `session.commit` After Select

```
def find_entry(self, inpath):
    inpath = inpath.rstrip('/')
    inpath = '/'.join(inpath.split('/')[:-1])
    entry = self.session.query(
        models.Gather).filter_by(path=inpath).first()
    self.session.commit()
    return entry
```

But this doesn't actually commit the session transaction and so when we rollback we still lose the data.

## Reasons And Other Effects

For performance reasons we have a set of code that selects data from a database, gets row IDs from two tables in said DB, and then uses the selected row IDs as foreign keys when we insert.

This is mainly done so that we don't have to query on each insert.

The problem is that if we run into a constraint or integrity errors while we're inserting than we have to do a `session.rollback`. We're finding that this `session.rollback` is killing our prior query even though they should logically be on different transactions.

In addition to our selected data if we have objects that inserted successfully that we'd like to reference for their IDs these are also removed after a `sessions.rollback`.

## Full Code

```py
class DBInserter:

    def __init__(self):
        # connection info here
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()

    def __del__(self):
        self.session.close()
        self.engine.dispose()

    def find_entry(self, inpath):
        inpath = inpath.rstrip('/')
        inpath = '/'.join(inpath.split('/')[:-1])
        entry = self.session.query(
            models.Gather).filter_by(path=inpath).first()
        return entry

    def build_insertable(self, jsonin, gather, lnn):
        """
        Build sqlalchemy object that is ready to be inserted into the db
        """
        object_dict = {}

        cluster = models.Cluster(
            guid = jsonin.get('guid'),
            )

        gather_id = None
        if gather:
            gather_id = gather.gather_id
            cluster.gather_id = gather_id
            gather.cluster_guid = jsonin.get('guid')
            gather.cluster_name = jsonin.get('name'),
            object_dict['gather'] = gather

        node_gather = models.NodeGather(
            gather_id = gather_id,
            lnn = lnn,
            checksum = jsonin.get('checksum'),
            checksum_valid = jsonin.get('checksum_valid'),
            compliance = jsonin.get('compliance'),
            encoding = jsonin.get('encoding'),
            joinmode = jsonin.get('joinmode'),
            master = jsonin.get('master'),
            maxid = jsonin.get('maxid'),
            timezone = jsonin.get('timezone'),
            )

        object_dict['cluster'] = cluster
        object_dict['node_gather'] = node_gather
        return object_dict

    def insert(self, insertable):
        """
        insert prepared sqlalchemy object into the db
        """    
        # Not doing batch inserts until we get single case to work properly.
        try:
            self.session.add(insertable['cluster'])
            self.session.commit()
        except IntegrityError:
            print('Prevented from inserting duplicate to cluster table')
            self.session.rollback()

        if insertable.get('gather'):
            try:
                self.session.add(insertable.get('gather'))
                self.session.commit()
            except IntegrityError:
                print('Prevented from inserting duplicate to gather table')
                self.session.rollback()

    def __call__(self, jsonin, path):
        path = path.rstrip('/')
        lnn = int(path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1])
        out = self.build_insertable(jsonin, self.find_entry(path), lnn)
        return out
```

## SQL

```
2016-03-08 01:38:52,438 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT gather.gather_id AS gather_gather_id, gather.cluster_guid AS gather_cluster_guid, gather.path AS gather_path, gather
.cluster_name AS gather_cluster_name, gather.gather_date AS gather_gather_date, gather.unfurl_start AS gather_unfurl_start, gather.unfurl_end AS gather_unfurl_end, gather.upload_date
AS gather_upload_date, gather.source_lnn AS gather_source_lnn, gather.last_full AS gather_last_full, gather.path_exists AS gather_path_exists, gather.type AS gather_type 
FROM gather 
WHERE gather.path = %(path_1)s 
LIMIT %(param_1)s
2016-03-08 01:38:52,438 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'param_1': 1, 'path_1': '/mnt/logs/REALPAGE/2015-12-14-005'}
2016-03-08 01:38:52,440 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2016-03-08 01:38:52,441 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2016-03-08 01:38:52,441 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT gather.gather_id AS gather_gather_id, gather.cluster_guid AS gather_cluster_guid, gather.path AS gather_path, gather
.cluster_name AS gather_cluster_name, gather.gather_date AS gather_gather_date, gather.unfurl_start AS gather_unfurl_start, gather.unfurl_end AS gather_unfurl_end, gather.upload_date
AS gather_upload_date, gather.source_lnn AS gather_source_lnn, gather.last_full AS gather_last_full, gather.path_exists AS gather_path_exists, gather.type AS gather_type 
FROM gather 
WHERE gather.gather_id = %(param_1)s
2016-03-08 01:38:52,441 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'param_1': 'd284c3f7983f94bac95e024038820f05475feddb2f24aec2cb52d42c343194dd'}
2016-03-08 01:38:52,444 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO cluster (guid, site_id) VALUES (%(guid)s, %(site_id)s)
2016-03-08 01:38:52,444 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'guid': '00074309e06ace7817523b06c7cbf76f7c08', 'site_id': None}
2016-03-08 01:38:52,445 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
```

Notice that there isn't a commit between the select and the rollback.

Halp.

Comment: What is your actual question? How to keep SQLAlchemy from expiring objects in the session when you roll back? AFAIK you can't. Depending on your requirements it may be acceptable to detach the objects from the session that you want to keep before you do the insert.

Comment: We got around this issue by making copies of the selected data. It's a real pain in the ass and I was hoping there's a way to make objects not expire on session.rollback. We've also considered opening two sessions. One for selecting data and one for inserting. I've never done anything like that before and don't know if that would even work.

Comment: It sounds to me that detaching from the session should work in your case. Two sessions should work too but that has additional overhead (two connections).

Comment: Note that you can save your objects from expiring on rollback by using `event.listen(session, 'after_rollback', lambda sess: sess.expunge_all(), once=True)`. This expunges all objects before rollback gets to expiring them and so modified attributes are not lost. Then you can add the objects back to the session.

Answer (score 0):

That's all beacuse of sqlAlchemy objects states and sessions, [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_state_management.html).

When you call rollback all your objects become expired and that's why empty.
You can read about it [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#rolling-back). Note, that even with option expire_on_commit=False your data will be expired.

> All objects not expunged are fully expired - this is regardless of the Session.expire_on_commit setting.

As other guys methioned in comments you can expunge objects before rollback to prevent their erasing.

```
self.session.expunge(object_dict['cluster'])
```

or

```
self.session.expunge_all()
```